# woocommerce_product_quick_edit_save hook not fired

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, save-post, quick-edit

I´m trying to add custom fields in the quick edit of woocommerce product.
I managed to show fields and populate with jquery but I don´t manage to save data updated.

```
add_action( 'quick_edit_custom_box', array( $action_class, $quick_edit_method_called ), 99, 3 );
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', array( $action_class, $quick_edit_script ), 99 );
if( $post_type_slug === 'product' ){
    add_action( 'woocommerce_product_quick_edit_save', array( $action_class, $quick_edit_save_post ), 99, 1 );
}else{
    add_action( 'save_post', array( $action_class, $quick_edit_save_post ), 99, 2 );
}
```

`quick_edit_custom_box` and `admin_enqueue_scripts` work very well but neither `woocommerce_product_quick_edit_save` nor `save_post` are fired when the administrator click on button 'update' in quick edit.

To test it, I added `wp_die('my test must stop here');` inside `$action_class::$quick_edit_save_post()`. No success.

Someone has got an idea ?

Comment: Hi @J.BizMai you should check this link by Misha Rudrastyh. just follow the steps.
https://rudrastyh.com/wordpress/quick-edit-tutorial.html

Comment: @NileshChouhan I know this page. quick_edit_custom_box, admin_enqueue_scripts work perfectly, My problem is save_post or woocommerce_product_quick_edit_save are not fired but others are fired. I don´t know why. I tried with or withour priority and 1 or 2 arguments without sucess. I will see if this part of code run only when the list are initiated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what was the problem.

the code with actions were wrapped bu this following code :

```
global pagenow;
if ( $pagenow === "edit.php" && isset( $_GET['post_type'] ) ){}
```

When there is an ajax call, `$pagenow === admin-ajax.php` and `$_GET === [ ["_fs_blog_admin"]=> string(4) "true" ]` so that could not be fired.